# Where does an Access query run using linked tables?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I use MS Access 2010 on my PC, to link MS SQL tables from our server on cloud.
When I run a query I wrote on Access on my PC involving the lined tables, does the query retreive data from the SQL server over the connection, or is there a cashed data locally on my PC that is used instead?

Simply the question is: In case of using linked tables in Access, does querying these tables run locally where Access database is in use or on the server?

Answer (score -1):

The query will run locally with ordinary queries and linked tables.  This means that Access will need to pull all of the data from the linked tables and filter the rows locally.  This can be very bad for performance if your WHERE clause only returns a small percentage of rows.

An alternative would be to use [pass through queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) where the query is executed on the server.  This means only the data you need will pass over the network and the performance could be far better.

Comment: That is not quite true. If Access is asked for a certain amount of data from a properly indexed table and the query uses the index, only the required data is pulled. I have been working quite a while with SQL Server and MS Access and I can get pretty good speed from the cloud.

Comment: @John Wu On the contarary, my aim is to use access to let use of local resources istead of running the query that consumes the SQL clouded server. That's why I don't want to use pass-through queries. I was thinking of which is better to use linked tables or shall I use importing tables and keep updating. Then in case of using linked tables I can create simplier solutions for users to use and this will safe server resources more for larger business uses.

Comment: @Fionnuala you may be right in general but in my experience Access seems to insist on downloading all primary key values before submitting a WHERE-restricted query for just the values it wants. With more than a few thousand rows this means unnecessarily downloading megabytes of primary key values every time this particular form is opened to display one record.